# HTML "compiler" / merging application

Tags: html, compiler-construction

I am working with a very big HTML file, which has a lot of content in the body section.
Are there any "compilers" or merging applications for HTML that can merge multiple HTML files?

Example:

a.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    INCLUDE "b.htm"
    <div>
        INCLUDE "c.htm"
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

b.htm

```
some text
<a href="#">Link</a>
INCLUDE "c.htm"
```

c.htm

```
more <span>text</span>
```

would be merged to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    some text
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    more <span>text</span>
    <div>
        more <span>text</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed – depending on your needs these offer drastically different mechanisms and tools.

One particular quite simple HTML compiler that is fashionable at the moment is [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/). Jekyll powers the blogging engine on GitHub Pages and is both easy to use and extensible.

In your case, you’d for instance write

```
{% include c.htm %}
```

instead of

```
INCLUDE "c.htm"
```

Comment: I looked into Jekyll, which is definitely an amazing software. But it is an overkill for a simple task like mine..

Answer (score 0):

I decided to write [htmlcat](https://github.com/fluidblue/htmlcat) for exactly this purpose.