# Merging HTML files in a SinglePage application

Tags: javascript, html, mvvm, single-page-application

I'm developing pure JS + HTML application. To keep the code clean I would like to separate my application into the several html files (i.e. ClientView.html, HistoryView.html etc). Based on user actions one or another view (or several views) would be displayed. Each view is supposed to have an underlying code in a separate JS file. 
What I really want to achieve is following:

- Develop view as HTML page (do not use any kind of javascript templating)
- Views and viewmodels are loaded on the fly (only loaded when needed)
- Some way to control dependencies.

I would be very thankful if you advice me a good start for that, as I'm quite new to modern html applications development. I myself is from WPF world, and I've been working with MVVM applications for a very long time, probably I'm wrong trying to bring same experience to javascript development.

I've found several posts about "compiling" html - ([HTML "compiler" / merging application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18045450/html-compiler-merging-application)), but I don't think that it is what I need.

p.s. In my project I'm very dependent from several features from Twitter Bootsrap (first of all from grid systems)

Answer (score 3):

Use a master page which contains some div to make the layout. Use JQuery to dynamically load various pages and insert into the div in the master page as required.

Comment: that's the easiest part, but I also need to dynamically load a lot of javascript with those views, run initializers etc. wondering if there's any framework for such stuff. In the end I'd like it to be as much declarative as possible, with little coding.